# 'Lower' object has no attribute 'partition'

Tags: python, django

There is a model that extends [django-polymorphic](http://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```
class FooQuerySet(PolymorphicQuerySet):
  ..
```

now when trying to use Django's `Lower` to make sure `order_by` is case insensitive

```
qs.order_by(Lower('name'))
```

getting:

> *** AttributeError: 'Lower' object has no attribute 'partition'

---

**Question:** is it possible that `PolymorphicQuerySet` is causing this error (since it works fine on regular querysets)?

Comment: try this once qs.order_by(lower_name = Lower('name'))

Comment: *** TypeError: order_by() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lower_name'

Comment: ohh sorry, try this qs.annotate(lower_name = Lower('name')).order_by('lower_name')

Comment: great, thanks, give a moment bro :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this as you need to `annotate` the `order_by` query before passing it to the `order_by`

```
qs.annotate(lower_name = Lower('name')).order_by('lower_name')
```